# How to differentiate with JSON based with key and without key by lodash groupBy()?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

The result of lodash `groupBy()` should give `{ "withType": [], "withOutType": [] }`.

```
const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, 'type', 'withOutType');
```

Is it possible to differentiate as two groups based on existence of `type` key in JSON ?

```js
const datas=[{_id:"5ea2ecbde53c090b4ba4fa12",firstName:"Dillon",surname:"Mclaughlin",guid:"a727438f-4ddc-4422-af4a-c7396fda73c3",isActive:true,balance:"$3,331.33",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd067a8ad1cb1f9e62",firstName:"Fleming",surname:"Austin",guid:"e228bbea-ef6b-4709-995c-bf485fa3665c",isActive:true,balance:"$1,869.92",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:35,type:"teacher"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd0d1a074b255a1349",firstName:"Kaufman",surname:"Alford",guid:"176fb7fe-b7bc-4574-8887-4252a042b24a",isActive:true,balance:"$2,163.34",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:29,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd1162ee44119aa0d3",firstName:"Sykes",surname:"Petty",guid:"92b13963-7d32-469c-be80-c88728a7842a",isActive:false,balance:"$2,728.46",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37},{_id:"5ea2ecbd297854a2f85909a4",firstName:"Stuart",surname:"Pickett",guid:"322031f9-1a71-44ae-b1cf-cbe7430b78b6",isActive:false,balance:"$1,725.25",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:25,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd6ef4a9bee37a223a",firstName:"Berg",surname:"Hewitt",guid:"ab05bed9-29e4-4570-aa12-fead954417b0",isActive:false,balance:"$2,935.72",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:31}];

const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, 'type', 'noneType');
console.log(splittedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

**Expected result**

```
{
  "withType": [],
  "withOutType": []
}
```

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: @AZ_ I need two group with exist object and another which doesn't have the key

Comment: @NinaScholz Just updated the question

Comment: Have a look at [partition](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#partition) e.g. `const [withType, withoutType] = _.partition(datas, item => item.type)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `_.partition()` to create two groups - one for truthy values, and the other for falsy. The destructure, and create the object:

```js
const datas=[{_id:"5ea2ecbde53c090b4ba4fa12",firstName:"Dillon",surname:"Mclaughlin",guid:"a727438f-4ddc-4422-af4a-c7396fda73c3",isActive:true,balance:"$3,331.33",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd067a8ad1cb1f9e62",firstName:"Fleming",surname:"Austin",guid:"e228bbea-ef6b-4709-995c-bf485fa3665c",isActive:true,balance:"$1,869.92",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:35,type:"teacher"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd0d1a074b255a1349",firstName:"Kaufman",surname:"Alford",guid:"176fb7fe-b7bc-4574-8887-4252a042b24a",isActive:true,balance:"$2,163.34",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:29,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd1162ee44119aa0d3",firstName:"Sykes",surname:"Petty",guid:"92b13963-7d32-469c-be80-c88728a7842a",isActive:false,balance:"$2,728.46",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37},{_id:"5ea2ecbd297854a2f85909a4",firstName:"Stuart",surname:"Pickett",guid:"322031f9-1a71-44ae-b1cf-cbe7430b78b6",isActive:false,balance:"$1,725.25",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:25,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd6ef4a9bee37a223a",firstName:"Berg",surname:"Hewitt",guid:"ab05bed9-29e4-4570-aa12-fead954417b0",isActive:false,balance:"$2,935.72",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:31}];

const [withType, withoutType] = _.partition(datas, 'type');
console.log({ withType, withoutType });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a solution like this:

```
const splits = [
    [...datas.filter(element => element.type)],
    [...datas.filter(element => !element.type)]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could supply a function as a second argument to `_.groupBy()` which will return `'withType'` if the current object has the `type` property (checked using [`_.has()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#has)), or it will return `'withoutType'` if it doesn't:

```js
const data = [{_id:"5ea2ecbde53c090b4ba4fa12",firstName:"Dillon",surname:"Mclaughlin",guid:"a727438f-4ddc-4422-af4a-c7396fda73c3",isActive:true,balance:"$3,331.33",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd067a8ad1cb1f9e62",firstName:"Fleming",surname:"Austin",guid:"e228bbea-ef6b-4709-995c-bf485fa3665c",isActive:true,balance:"$1,869.92",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:35,type:"teacher"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd0d1a074b255a1349",firstName:"Kaufman",surname:"Alford",guid:"176fb7fe-b7bc-4574-8887-4252a042b24a",isActive:true,balance:"$2,163.34",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:29,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd1162ee44119aa0d3",firstName:"Sykes",surname:"Petty",guid:"92b13963-7d32-469c-be80-c88728a7842a",isActive:false,balance:"$2,728.46",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37},{_id:"5ea2ecbd297854a2f85909a4",firstName:"Stuart",surname:"Pickett",guid:"322031f9-1a71-44ae-b1cf-cbe7430b78b6",isActive:false,balance:"$1,725.25",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:25,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd6ef4a9bee37a223a",firstName:"Berg",surname:"Hewitt",guid:"ab05bed9-29e4-4570-aa12-fead954417b0",isActive:false,balance:"$2,935.72",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:31}];

const splittedData = _.groupBy(data, o => _.has(o, 'type') ? 'withType' : 'withoutType'); 
console.log(splittedData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `type` exists in the object and get an object with grouped by `true` or `false`.

```js
const datas=[{_id:"5ea2ecbde53c090b4ba4fa12",firstName:"Dillon",surname:"Mclaughlin",guid:"a727438f-4ddc-4422-af4a-c7396fda73c3",isActive:true,balance:"$3,331.33",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd067a8ad1cb1f9e62",firstName:"Fleming",surname:"Austin",guid:"e228bbea-ef6b-4709-995c-bf485fa3665c",isActive:true,balance:"$1,869.92",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:35,type:"teacher"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd0d1a074b255a1349",firstName:"Kaufman",surname:"Alford",guid:"176fb7fe-b7bc-4574-8887-4252a042b24a",isActive:true,balance:"$2,163.34",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:29,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd1162ee44119aa0d3",firstName:"Sykes",surname:"Petty",guid:"92b13963-7d32-469c-be80-c88728a7842a",isActive:false,balance:"$2,728.46",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:37},{_id:"5ea2ecbd297854a2f85909a4",firstName:"Stuart",surname:"Pickett",guid:"322031f9-1a71-44ae-b1cf-cbe7430b78b6",isActive:false,balance:"$1,725.25",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:25,type:"student"},{_id:"5ea2ecbd6ef4a9bee37a223a",firstName:"Berg",surname:"Hewitt",guid:"ab05bed9-29e4-4570-aa12-fead954417b0",isActive:false,balance:"$2,935.72",picture:"http://placehold.it/32x32",age:31}];

const splittedData = _.groupBy(datas, o => 'type' in o ? "withType" : "withOutType");
console.log(splittedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```